# Difference between SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER and SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR

Tags: android, orientation, screen-orientation

While developing an Android app, I've found two ActivityInfo attributes for setting the screen orientation.

The attributes having USER are as follows:

1. SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER
2. SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER_LANDSCAPE
3. SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER_PORTRAIT

The attributes having SENSOR are as follows:

1. SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR
2. SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE
3. SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT

What is the difference between the SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER and SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[From source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#screenOrientation)

> **The attributes having USER are as follows.**
>
> SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER

Use the user's current preferred orientation of the handset. Corresponds to SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER.

> SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER_LANDSCAPE

Would like to have the screen in landscape orientation, but if the user has enabled sensor-based rotation then we can use the sensor to change which direction the screen is facing. Corresponds to SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER_LANDSCAPE.

> SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER_PORTRAIT

Would like to have the screen in portrait orientation, but if the user has enabled sensor-based rotation then we can use the sensor to change which direction the screen is facing. Corresponds to SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER_PORTRAIT.

> **The attributes having SENSOR are as follows.**
>
> SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR

Orientation is determined by a physical orientation sensor: the display will rotate based on how the user moves the device. Ignores user's setting to turn off sensor-based rotation. Corresponds to SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR.

> SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE

Would like to have the screen in landscape orientation, but can use the sensor to change which direction the screen is facing. Corresponds to SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE.

> SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT

Would like to have the screen in portrait orientation, but can use the sensor to change which direction the screen is facing. Corresponds to SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT.

Comment: But what is the user's current preferred orientation of the handset? How is this set?

Comment: @alexbirkett: It's set in device settings (by user himself - hence the name)

Comment: **user preferred** we usually can change (toggle on/off) in the notification panel of your device